# how to speed up data processing using camel and spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am trying to do following things with high performance. I want to process one huge file with following requirement. I have one huge file like some 20,000,00L records with following format.

**Format and Sample Data**

```
STUDENT_NAME|STUDENT_ID|MOBILE_NUMBER|EMAIL_ID
Ramesh      |12345     |928xxxxx     |test@test.com
```

I have some business logic during this operation. like above sample record, i will be having 20,000,00L record in one file. During my business operation i will do update some of above records. but I don't want to use any for loop kind of thing. I should able to randomly update values.
Technology I am using
Camel & Java Spring

Please suggest me best approach for doing this successfully.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. You've already decided to use Camel and Spring, so clearly you know the tools for the job. What have you tried, or where are you confused about approaching a solution?

Comment: second @AdamHawkes comment...also, can you clarify why you can't use a loop and what you mean by being able to randomly update values?

Comment: currently how i am doing is through batch processing using camel aggregator. but i want to do this in single shots. and as i told during my business operation i may have chance to update some of the records present in file. so my requirement is i need to process the whole file records and after my business operation i will create a new file with updated values. update here meaning is mobile number or email may change to some students...

Comment: I'm sorry, it's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Could you post your route and explain at which points you'd like to make improvements?

Comment: There are a 1000 ways to do this however without seeing more detail we can all just speculate on what is going to work. You mention loading this in a single shot? If you wanted to update all the records at once you will need to look at some sort of staging table inside a SQL server. Please add more details.